# Gnome app search engine is not finding any apps

Tags: gnome, manjaro, gnome-shell

I am using Manjaro, and a recent update may have broke something, when I use the super key (the windows key on my keyboard), my windows are all displayed, and there is a little search input field at the top, in this field I used to enter the name of an application like gedit, or anything else.

No this search engine doesn't find any application, I can launch them if I know the command for it, and use the alt + f2 shortcut, or a terminal.

How can I reset this search engine ?